# Segmentation fault when trying to run executable

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

When running this you should get a segment fault.
It must be something with wrong usage of the private class variables in the function.
Just compile it and try running it.
This code was edited by PaulMcKenzie!

**Affine.cpp**

```
#include <string>

class Affine
{
    std::string m_encryptedText;
    std::string m_decryptedText;
    std::string m_text;
    int m_aKey;
    int m_bKey;

    public:
        void encrypt();
        Affine(const std::string &text,int aKey,int bKey) : m_text(text)                       
        {
           setKey(aKey, bKey);
        }
        void setKey(int x, int y) { m_aKey = x; m_bKey = y; }
};

void Affine::encrypt()
{
    m_decryptedText = m_text;
    for(int i=0;m_decryptedText[i] != '\0';i++)
    {
        m_encryptedText[i] = static_cast<char>(m_aKey*m_decryptedText[i]+m_bKey);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Affine a("hey", 1, 2);
    a.encrypt();
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: *The error appears only when trying to run it.*  -- In other words, you have a bug.  Successful compilation only means that there are no syntax errors.

Comment: What else do you need? Don't expect it to throw a compile time error. It will just not run once compiled. The problem should be in these parts of the code. Do you see any segmentation fault in here?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: It says segmentation fault. Soo how do I fix it?

Comment: Just a guess that `m_encryptedText` is initially empty and so `m_encryptedText[i]` is out of range. Use `push_back` to add a character to an empty string.

Comment: @alienCY -- Your program has a bug.  You fix it by debugging your application.   A segmentation fault can be due to many things.

Comment: @BoPersson: Push_back didn't fix it, but that was also an error. So now m_decryptedText is the problem. Copying strings with the = I think it doesn't work in this example? ( I don't know how to debug in vim PaulMcKenzie )

Comment: 1) Please post a [mcve].  2) You don't fix runtime errors by guessing and changing code and hoping something sticks. 3) Debugging and using a debugger is part and parcel of learning how to write programs.  No one writes a program that runs perfect the first time, and learning debugging is mandatory, not voluntary.

Comment: @alienCY [This is what we mean by a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2454686ed720f15a).  Bits and pieces of code will not show us, how, when, where, what data is used, etc. to reproduce the error.  A full example, such as what I linked to is what is required.

Comment: The problem is Definately within the encrypt function or it is a part of it at least. Since it's segmentation fault it should be something with the memory and the way I initialize, copy ( whatever ) the variables.

Comment: See my comment.  We do not know **how** you're using the function, what data, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: oh Ok. I guess I should have re written it so it was compile-able and run-able. Sorry about that. ( You have enlightened me )

Comment: You encrypt your message only until you find the first newline? Funny encryption mechanism...

Comment: @manni66: I will improve it once this is fixed but yeah you are right I should count the length of string and iterate that many times.

Comment: Ok, with the added code we can see that the string `"hey"` doesn't contain a `'\n'` so the loop does not terminate properly. You might instead use `.size()` for that.

Comment: @BoPersson: So foolish >.< I will edit now it should have been '/0' the last character in every string right?

Comment: No, std::string is not terminated with '\0'

Comment: @manni66: Only c style strings huh? But isn't std::string implemented with c style strings? So it's removed huh? :/

Comment: @alienCY -- The length of a `std::string` is determined by the `std::string::size()` member function, not by null-termination.

Comment: @manni66 For any `std::string s`, `s[s.size()]` is valid and guaranteed to return a reference to a `char` having the value `'\0'` In other words, `std::string` is effectively NUL-terminated.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik AFAIK that's right since C++ 11, before that was only true for the const operator.

Comment: @manni66 That's true. That said, `for(auto& c : m_decryptedText)` construct also requires C++11 conformance, and yet you didn't hesitate to suggest it. In think in year 2017 it is OK to assume at least C++11 unless stated otherwise.

Comment: It hurts going below zero ): Anyway thanks for you help people!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, one should assume at least C++ 11. But in the case of range based for loop the compiler will complain, operator[] will just generate UB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string::operator[]` does not do bounds checking; `std::string::at` does, and throws an exception if an out-of-bounds access is attempted.

You're looping over the string without checking if it stays inside the bounds of the string. The loop only terminates if a newline (`\n`) is encountered. If there is no newline, then it will loop until it reaches the bounds and what happens then is undefined.

There are a number of problems with your code. For one it's not very C++-ish. You should use either `foreach` or iterators or (C++ 11 and onward) `for(auto &…: …)` to implement the loop constraints. Any check on a terminating condition should be extra; they could be put into the loop condition check, but it's usually easier to read to have it just as a test-if-break right at the start and have the rest after in the loop body, like this:

```
for(…){
    if( loop_break_condition ){ break }

    …
}
```

On a side note: Cesar Ciphers are not really encryption at all. There are only 26 possible keys. That alone would be easy enough to brute force, but given a long enough cipher text you don't even have to do that: Just determine the letter frequencies in the cipher text, sort them, as associate the sorted letter frequencies of plain text in the assumed language. For a simple rotation cipher on Latin character you can look at the highest frequency letter and assume that it's an `e`, giving you the key.

Comment: I'm working on a project about classical ciphers: https://github.com/alienCY/CEDA

Answer (score 1):

Don't test on some terminating char. A std::string knows it's size

```
for(auto& c : m_decryptedText)
{
    c = static_cast<char>(m_aKey * c + m_bKey);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help people! :D I will try to learn how to debug in vim and learn more about strings. For now I used for each loop to fix my foolish mistake of making an infinite(?) loop and accessing memory addresses that I shouldn't have accessed.

This is the code for the function that works:

```
m_decryptedText = m_text;

for(char character : m_decryptedText)
{
    m_encryptedText.push_back(static_cast<char>(m_aKey*character + m_bKey));
}
```